# Переместил storage папку в public, безопасно ли это?

Tags: php, laravel, hosting

Веб Сервер не позволяет создать ссылку на ***storage*** папку, 
решил вопрос просто переместив папку **storage** в ***public***, все работает,

Но  правильно ли я поступил, безопасно ли это для сайта ?
Если не безопасно, то как поступить правильно ?

Если есть ссылки на эту тему буду рад посмотреть.

Comment: ну не то что бы прям совсем безопасно, но и не критично, просто запретите внешний доступ к этой папке и её содержимому.

Comment: А как запретить внешний доступ к этому файлу

Comment: Ну если у вас `apache`/`ngnix`, то загуглите и все найдете, думаю гугл даст более подробные инструкции, чем я

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А вы пробовали создавать символическую ссылку на локальном проекте, а не через хостинг 
(по `ssh` или как вы там делали) и потом деплоить на хостинг?

Также можете попробовать следующие команды для создания символической ссылки:

Unix:

```
ln -s /path/to/laravel/storage/avatars /path/to/laravel/public/avatars
```

Windows:

```
mklink /j /path/to/laravel/public/avatars /path/to/laravel/storage/avatars
```

В папке storage есть же папки *framework*, *logs*, их надеюсь не перемещали? :) 
Если говорить о папке `storage_path('app')` то она содержит папки разных ваших локальных хранилищ. Если посмотреть в конфиг *filesystems.php*, то видно какие у вас хранилища (disks), по умолчанию есть следующие локальные хранилища:

```
    'local' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app'),
    ],

    'public' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
        'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
        'visibility' => 'public',
    ],
```

[local](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/filesystem#the-local-driver) не является публичным и содержит то что в корне *storage/app*. Поэтому переносить весь *storage/app* не правильно. Переместить *storage/app/public* в *public* еще имеет смысл. Но после такого перемещения вы не сможете использовать public disk по такому принципу:

```
Storage::disk('local')->put('file.txt', 'Contents');
```

Точнее сможете, но это надо менять в конфиге `'root' => storage_path('app/public'),` на что-то подобное: `public_path('storage')`, не знаю хорошая ли это практика.

Надеюсь помог чем-то.

Comment: Пробовал на локальном сервере создавать символическую ссылку но после загрузки на хостинг ,  он перестал работать (наверное по соображениям безопасности сервера)

Comment: @a_mine попробуйте в поддержку написать, если у хостинга с этим проблема то возможно всплывут и другие проблемы. что за хостинг интересно?

Comment: Символическая ссылка  на хостинге www.000webhost  начала работать правильно, после  повторной отправки через ftp папки public . Ошибка была в том что после  zip  архивации и распаковки почему то  символическая ссылка storage  не работала , повторная отправка все исправило

Answer (score 0):

Я посмотрел на курсах как делают специалисты от https://www.udemy.com/

Для отображения рисунков создаю путь: public_images:

в storage/app/public/**public_images**

запускаем команду:

```
php artisan storage:link
```

и директория [/storage/product_images] появится ссылкой в нашем сайте/public/public_images

```
•   !!!А изображения которые в БД размещаем в папку storage/public/public_images
```

а с вида подтягиваю картинку как обычно:

```
<td>
<img src="{{ Storage::url('product_images/'.$product['image'])}}" width="100" height="100" style="max-height: 220px">
</td>
```

или так:

```
<td>
    <img src="{{asset('storage')}}/product_images/{{$product['image']}}" width="100" height="100" >
</td>
```